# how to switch on a nullable variable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have the following code

```
 switch (xn.SelectSingleNode("@type").InnerText)
            {
                case "int":
                case "int16":
                case "int32":v=int.Parse(xn.InnerText);break;
                default:v=xn.InnerText; break;

            }
```

The xn.SelectSingleNode("@type") may return null,
How can I declare switch(x) to be nullable

Comment: The `null` value returned shall be processed by your `default` behaviour within your `switch` instruction. Is it not what you want?

Comment: @Will, `null` would be the result of `SelectSingleNode`, in which case invoking `InnerText` would be an NRE.

Comment: @Anthony: Agreed. I had not looked to the OP's question under that angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var type = xn.SelectSingleNode("@type");
if (type == null)
{
    // Handle the case
}
else
{
    switch (type.InnerText)
    {
        case "int":
        case "int16":
        case "int32":v=int.Parse(xn.InnerText);break;
        default:v=xn.InnerText; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Verifying for null reference is always a good habit, in my humble point of view. =)

Answer (score 2):

Strings, being objects, are always nullable. Just include null as a possibility in your switch statement:

```
switch (xn.SelectSingleNode("@type").InnerText)
{
    case "int":
    case "int16":
    case "int32":v=int.Parse(xn.InnerText);break;
    case null:
        // Handle case
        break;
    default:v=xn.InnerText; break;

}
```

Comment: +1 You got it, lean and swift, keeping both simplicity and readability for programmers. What simplest than handling `null`!? I like it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this (expanded for readability)

> ```
> var node = xn.SelectSingleNode("@type");
> var innerText = (node == null ? (string)null : node.InnerText);
> switch (innertext)
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (xn.SelectSingleNode("@type").InnerText) {
    case "int":
    case "int16":
    case "int32":
        v = int.Parse(xn.InnerText);
        break;
    default: 
        v = string.IsNullOrEmpty(xn.InnerText) ? null : xn.InnerText; // Here you shall avoid the `NullReferenceException`.
        break;
}
```

Besides, if I understand correctly, `v` looks like it is an `int`, so you might wish to consider assigning it to `0` when the `xn.InnerText` returns null.

```
v = string.IsNullOrEmpty(xn.InnerText) ? 0 : xn.InnerText;
```